# How to register an Excel Addin COM to be used by x64 Microsft Excel (2019)

Tags: c#, excel, excel-addins, excel-automation

I am struggling to make a C# COM Addin visible for x64 Microstf Excel (2019). Until now my Addin is visible only for x86 Microsoft Excel, and never for the Microsoft Excel x64.

My Addin (Class Library) is compiled to AnyCPU, and is very basic, i have created only one class, with one function, no complex Dlls are referenced, i just need it to be visible for the moment.

I am using the code below for COM Registration:

---

```
    [ComRegisterFunctionAttribute]
    public static void RegisterFunction(Type type)
    {
        Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(GetSubKeyName(type));
    }



    [ComUnregisterFunctionAttribute]
    public static void UnregisterFunction(Type type)
    {
        Registry.ClassesRoot.DeleteSubKey(GetSubKeyName(type), false);
    }



    private static string GetSubKeyName(Type type)
    {
        string s = @"CLSID\{" + type.GUID.ToString().ToUpper() + @"}\Programmable";

        Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey("CLSID\\{" +
                            type.GUID.ToString().ToUpper() + "}\\InprocServer32");

        if (key != null)
        {
            key.SetValue("", System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.System) +
                             @"\mscoree.dll");
        }

        return s;
    }
```

---

The code above works perfectly for x86 Excel.

After doing my researchs, i understood that the COM Addin should be registered in the x64 Regitry to be visible for x64 Excel, i used the following lines to do that but nothing worked:

---

```
    // Version 1 : Registration to "Excel\\Addins" path

    [ComRegisterFunction()]
    private static void ComRegister(Type type)
    {
        string keyPath = "Software\\Microsoft\\Office\\Excel\\AddIns\\{" + type.GUID.ToString().ToUpper() + "}";
        RegistryKey baseKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
        RegistryKey key = baseKey.CreateSubKey(keyPath);
        if (key != null)
            key.SetValue("", System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.System) + @"\mscoree.dll");
    }



    // Version 2 : Restration to "Wow6432Node"

    [ComRegisterFunction]
    public static void RegisterFunction(Type type)
    {
        string s = @"Wow6432Node\\CLSID\{" + type.GUID.ToString().ToUpper() + @"}\Programmable";

        Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey("Wow6432Node\\CLSID\\{" +
                                                                                            type.GUID.ToString().ToUpper() + "}\\InprocServer32");

        if (key != null)
        {
            key.SetValue("", System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.System) +
                             @"\mscoree.dll");
        }
        Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(s);
```

### }

Can anyone help me make this very basic Addin work for x64 Excel ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: As far as I remember I had similar issue with Excel Add-in. In case of x64 office the keys should be put both to: 
Software\\Microsoft\\Office\\Excel\\AddIns\\ and \\Software\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Office\\Excel\\AddIns\\. 
Did You try this?

Comment: Creating a key in a method named "GetSubKeyName()" is quite misleading.  And done wrong, delete "Programmable".  This can't work for x86 either.  Version 2 is wrong for x64, delete "Wow6432Node".  You do strongly favor using RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey() so you can specify the correct view.

Comment: @Mikisz yes i have tried that, i can see that a key with my GUID was created and "mscoree.dll" is inside but as usual, i can't see my Addin in Excel.

Comment: @HansPassant, yes "GetSubKeyName()" is misleading , that was done 10 years ago by some other developer. But gain, it is working for x86, and we were using that for years.
For version 2, i already tested that too. But actually the weired thing is that i only see "mscoree.dll" in the specified paths and never a REG_SZ having the name of my Addin.